# Fetch more than 50K data through rest api and store into Android Local Storage(SQLite)

Tags: android, rest, android-sqlite

I need some help regarding fetch bulk data through background service and store it into android local storage,

I don't want to use pagination, I mean when the app activity is launch that time background service is call and its running until fetching is not completed(50k data row).

Thanks in advance.
:-)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that Android's [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) are perfect for. They fire off in the background and are designed to do this exact thing.

Essentially, you just subclass the service and write your download logic in that. Once the download is complete, you can then, depending on how you created your service, notify your app of the result. If the service was bound, you can have the activity that bound to the service register a listener. If the service was started (an Android term for started without an explicit bound recipient) then you can fire of an Intent indicating the completion of the task.